# bijective function $f:\mathbb{N}^{n} \to \mathbb{N}$ (a map of a number system with base eq to $W \to \infty$)

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-systems

I am trying to find a bijective function (a map):
$$
f: \mathbb{N}^{n} \to \mathbb{N} \\
f(x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3},..., x_{n}) = y
$$

That behaves like this: 
$f(0, \ 0, \ 0, \ 0, \ ..., \ 0) = A$ 
$f(1, \ 0, \ 0, \ 0, \ ..., \ 0) = B$ 
$f(2, \ 0, \ 0, \ 0, \ ..., \ 0) = C$ 
$...$ 
 
$f(W, \ 0, \ 0, \ 0, \ ..., \ 0) = D$ 
$f(W, \ 1, \ 0, \ 0, \ ..., \ 0) = E$ 
$f(W, \ 2, \ 0, \ 0, \ ..., \ 0) = F$ 
$...$ 
 
$f(W, \ W, \ 0, \ 0, \ ..., \ 0) = G$ 
$...$ 
 
$f(W, \ W, \ W, \ W, \ ..., \ W) = H$

Where:

- $W \to \infty$
- $A \lt B \lt C \lt \ ... \ \lt D \lt E \lt F \lt \ ... \ \lt G \lt \
     ... \ \lt H$
- $A = y_{min}$
- $H = y_{max}$

I know that this is a bit "similar" to how the number base system works 
*(assume base = $W$, $x_{1}$ would be a number of units, $x_{2}$ a number of tens and so on)*.

I am aware that the simplest function that fulfills my requirements is: 
$$
f(x_{1}, \ x_{2}, \ x_{3}, \ ..., \ x_{n}) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i} \cdot W^{\left(i - 1\right)}
$$

Unfortunately, there is a problem; this solution doesn't like infinities. And it's rather critical for me to be able to "set" $W = \infty$ *(yes, I know that nothing can be equal to $\infty$, "equal" is just to represent a general idea)*.

I need this because I am trying to implement a tree-like structure in C++ that doesn't restrict me on the number of children a node can have and still allows me to sort the tree in a meaningful way.

Any ideas are more than welcome.

P.S.

- $n$ would be a height of a tree
- $W$ would be a max number of children a node can have,
- $\left(x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3},..., x_{n}\right)$ are the coordinates on the tree ($x_{1}$ nodes on the 1st level, $x_{2}$ nodes on the 2nd level, etc)

Comment: It cannot really be ordered in the way you want. You cannot have an infinite sequence $A < B < C <...$ and *then*, after all those numbers, a greater sequence of numbers $D < E <...$. Unless I haven't understood what you ask, this seems odd

Comment: @CharlesMadeline no, you have understood me correctly. I did want an infinite sequence of $A \lt B \lt C \lt \ ...$ and then a "greater" sequence of $ ... \ \lt D \lt E \lt F \lt \ ...$. And as if it was not enough I tried to fill all those sequences inside $\mathbb{N}$... I see now that such operations would have taken me outside of $\mathbb{N}$. Sometimes to see an error of one's own ways, one needs to ask a correct question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your function correctly, you want something like the following:

$$f:\mathbb{N\cup\infty}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$$
$$\forall i>0 \in \mathbb{N} f(i,0,\ldots,0)<f(\infty,1,0,\ldots,0)$$

This however is not possible, as the set $\{f(\mathbb{N},0,\ldots,0)\}$ is unbounded, since we have $f(i,0,\ldots,0)\leq f(i+1,0,\ldots,0)+1$, hence $f(i,0\ldots,0)\geq i$.

There is a generalisation of the natural numbers "called the ordinary numbers", which essentially exactly does what you want, but as you want to implement this on C it's probably not helping.

Alternatives that could help you: Change your domain to a subset of $\mathbb{N}$ or change the image to $\mathbb{Q}$